# Preprocessing configurations file before using properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my appsettings.json file I have a couple of properties that need to be replaced at runtime.
Example :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnection": "ReferenceToActualSqlConnection"
}
```

The appsettings file is loaded into a IConfiguration file and the value is used further

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:SqlConnection").Value);
        });
```

Except that before actually using it, I want to replace "ReferenceToActualSqlConnection" with the actual value in a separate module that has the IConfiguration file injected from the DI container, so the method above uses the replaced value. As far as I'm concerned the injection goes one way, so I can get the values in the preprocess module, but not get them updated back before usage. The module is registered as:

```
services.AddTransient<IConfigProcessor, ConfigProcessor>();
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: The asp.net core config is layered. You can overwrite settings using environment variables and different json files for different environments. Have you reviewed the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/ if you really do need something custom you could write a Configuration provider

Comment: In the Startup class you can register your IConfiguration file however you want, either with the values from appsettings or from other sources. So all the classes that get IConfiguration injected will receive the proper values. Eg. services.Configure<IConfiguration>(x=>{x.ConnectionString = "...";});

Comment: @PopaAndrei the problem was not how to statically set values in the configuration within the Startup.cs file, rather how to set this values outside this file. Injecting the IConfiguration in the specified service does not work. In the end the solution was to update the values (i.e. call the ConfigProcessor within the Startup.cs file)